# RegEX pattern for confirming only 1 domain is in a list of email addresses

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out what a regex pattern would be if I'm looking for 1 domain only in a list of email addresses.

Ex., I have a list of 3 email addresses; number1@gmail.com, number2@gmail.com, number3@gmail.com.  I want to check with Regex to confirm that only gmail.com addresses are in the list and confirm true.

If a different domain, like @yahoo.com, is present, then I want it to return false.

I have started with the following:

^(?!\S+@(?!gmail.com)\S+$).*$

but that only seems to confirm if gmail.com is present, not if it's the only email in the list.

If I have try number1@google.com, number2@gmail.com, it comes back as true.

Comment: Do you have to do this with a regexp? Loop through all the emails in the list, split them at `@`, and check if the domain is something other than `gmail.com`.

Comment: Please show some code. We can't provide solid help if we don't know if you have a `List<String>`, or a CSV String of emails, or something else. An [mcve] would be great

Comment: Why do you need regex? How about `boolean allGmail = list.stream().allMatch(s -> s.endsWith("@gmail.com"));` instead?

Comment: The initial request was restricted to RegEx as that was primary option for use in a Salesforce Flow formula.  However, after connecting with a teammate the idea is being scrapped in favor of an invocable APEX method.   Thanks to those that attempted to respond!

Comment: [`^(?=.*?@gmail\.com(,|$))(?!.*?@(?!gmail\.com(,|$))).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/J13Fqb/1)